# How to add a timestamp to my Python app uwsgi log?

Tags: logging, uwsgi

My Python application sends logs to stderr, UWSGI redirects it into /var/log/uwsgi/app/myapplication.log.
What is  the simplest way to prefix my app log output with a timestamp?
I prefer to do this with uwsgi.ini config, w/o change application code.

TIA,
Vitaly

Answer (score 4):

UWSGI ini file example

```
daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi/app.log
log-reopen = true
log-date = [%%Y:%%m:%%d %%H:%%M:%%S]
```

Output:
`[2018:10:15 23:05:39] - spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 26668, cores: 1)`

Answer (score 4):

To make this work in ini file, i had to add log-strftime param, like:

```
log-date = %%Y-%%m-%%d %%H:%%M:%%S
logformat-strftime
log-format = [%(ftime)]
```

prints:

```
[2019-08-05 13:49:16]
```

Comment: Almost. This prints the datestamp and nothing else. I think the `log-format` also needs parameters like `%(message)`. Unless you actually want pages of identical timestamps in your log.

Answer (score 3):

--logdate will do the trick.

eventually it takes an optional strftime-like string:

--logdate="%s"

will add the unix time as well as

--logdate="%d/%m/%Y"

will add the day/month/year prefix

Comment: +1 How can I make this work with an `ini` file? I tried `logdate = "%s"`, but the logs are still written without a date.

Comment: config files have the concept of placeholders, so you need to escape %, in your case it will be logdate = %%s

Comment: `logdate` only changes the timestamp before the uwsgi messages, not before the pythonic output.

Comment: Roberto, thank you!
Unfortunately, "logdate" and "logformat"  modify only UWSGI logs, not my application  logs.

Comment: then you need log encoders: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/LogEncoders.html